# Cannot pass Querying IP through Load Balancer

Tags: curl, go, ip, load-balancing, ip-address

I'm using a TCP Load Balancer from (https://github.com/darkhelmet/balance) and when i request it, the balanced server endpoints list the requested IP as that  of the TCP Load Balancer, and not the querying IP.

My curl query is as follows:

`curl --request GET --header "TokenAuth: secrettoken" "http://loadbalancerip:8080/v1/apiroute/avalue"`

Which then internally routes to the api servers from the Load Balancer.

**My problem is once it hits the api server the ip being listed is loadbalancerip, and not the user requester ip**

Am I doing my curl request incorrect? All of my api servers and load balancer are bound to `:port` not `ip:port`

Comment: while i cannot speak for the LB you are using - from personal experience it is common practice for load balancers to forward originating IP in a header - a common one being https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: @syllabix i added it as a header field in curl and works great thanks.